# ¿Cómo traducir "lean manufacturing"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, significado, vocabulario-técnico

En el campo de los procesos de manufactura o fabricación existe en inglés una metodología denominada "**lean manufacturing**".

El sitio [leanproduction](https://www.leanproduction.com/) tiene la siguiente defición en inglés:

> The core idea of **lean manufacturing** is actually quite
>   simple…
>   relentlessly work on eliminating waste from the manufacturing
>   process.

Lo que entiendo es que **lean manufacturing** es trabajar incansablemente o constantemente en eliminar el desperdicio del proceso de manufactura.

En algunos sitios encontré que traducen "**lean manufacturing**" como "**manufactura eficiente**", pero veo que no logra captar la idea que transmite la palabra **lean** que en español significa: delgado, esbelto, austero, magro.

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has visto https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=lean+manufacturing?  Por ejemplo: "Las ventajas de la fabricación ajustada van más allá", "programas de fabricación asociados a técnicas Lean".

Comment: No sé, para mí sí transmite la idea. Tal vez dándole el prefijo *ultra-* o algo.

Comment: Para la respuesta que pusé, me dieron un -1. ¿Por qué atacar al mensagero? Lo pueden averiguar en site:.es/site:.pe/site:.co y site.ar. Y debe de haber otros...

Answer (score 1):

Se dice producción ajustada. Es una producción que se ajusta a las necesidades del momento sin despilfarro de materiales y recursos.

¿Qué es la producción ajustada o Lean Manufacturing?

[lean manufacturing in Spanish](https://www.eaeprogramas.es/empresa-familiar/que-es-la-produccion-ajustada-o-lean-manufacturing)

Aqui tienes la historia:
[lean manufacturing](http://www.masterlogistica.es/efectivo-sistema-lean-manufacturing/)

Algunos también dicen: producción esbelta

Comment: La palabra **ajustada** transmite mejor la idea original en inglés.

Comment: yo lo he escuchado como manufactura esbelta (área del noroeste de México)

Comment: @alvalongo Yo dije **ajustada**. No entiendo tu comentario. Tampoco entiendo los dos votos negativos que me dieran. Que falta de sensatez hay por aqui.

Answer (score 0):

En mi humilde opinión es uno de esos casos que simplemente no se usa la traducción literal del inglés simplemente porque no hizo eco en la gente de la industria en cuestión. En el área de las tecnologías de información hay muchos ejemplos similares y para los cuales se usa ya sea la forma en inglés, una forma "castellanizada" del término en inglés o una traducción distinta al término original como en este caso.

Si la industria esta adoptando el término "manufactura eficiente" pues te va a resultar difícil ir en contra de ello, personalmente yo usaría "manufactura sin desperdicio" basado en tu explicación, pero nuevamente es mi muy personal opinión.